# Send choice Value instead choice key from Symfony form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need to send from Symfony form **ChoiceType::class**

But I don't need choices keys, I need to send choices values.

Is that is possible?

```
 $form->add('section', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 'value1',
                    2 => 'value2'

                ),
          ));
```

I just want to send value1 if I chose **value1**,

not **key 1** as default.

Comment: What version of Symfony you are using, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since Symfony 2.7] In any case you can play with choice value through `choice_value` option and a Closure function ([Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value)):

```
$form->add('section', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choice_value' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
        return $value;
    } 
));
```

Useful for dynamic `choices`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

`array_flip ($array)`

[refer to php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reverse it. Also, I don't think you need 'mapped'.
Try this:

```
$form->add(
    'section',
    ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'choices' => [
            'value1' => 1,
            'value2' => 2,
        ],
    ]
);
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, but this is just example, I get array from Entity, wich is iterated from 0 to array length.

Comment: You should normally post your 'real' code, not something that is completely different, otherwise it makes it very hard for people on so to support you.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer and I think its a major flaw on behalf of the Symfony developers. They seem to have confused themselves around the term "value", i.e. in a form the "value" is the key of an array but any normal array coming from the outside is key/value where the "key" is the value to be used on the form. Confusing right? Long story short, just wrap your key/value array in an `array_flip` and all will be well.

Answer (score 2):

Mayby a bit late but i've made this and it works perfect. Without `array_flip`. Mayby for someone it 'll be usefull.

```php
$dataUsers = [];
$users     = [
    ['id' => 1, 'firstname' => 'joe', 'lastname' => 'doe'],
    ['id' => 2, 'firstname' => 'will', 'lastname' => 'fog'],
];

foreach ($users as $u) {
    $dataUsers[] = (object)['id' => $u['id'], 'label' => $u['firstname']];
}

$builder
    ->add('users', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $dataUsers,
        'choice_label' => function ($value) {
            if (is_object($value)) {
                return $value->label;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        },
        'choice_value' => function ($value) {
            if (is_object($value)) {
                return $value->id;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        },
        'data' => (object)[ 'id' => 2]
    ]);
```